# How do I use toString to retrieve my information in my class and how do I get my method to calculate the "GPA" in this class?

Tags: java

My question is how do I get the gpa that I have listed in my constructor class to compile. Every time I try to compile it, I get a .class expected error. I'm rather new to java so please forgive my incompetence. My teacher wants us to calculate a a students gpa by dividing the number of points by classes in our constructor class. Then she wants us to use toString to retrieve our students information, which I do not know how to do as we have gone over toString once. Sorry if my explanation is a little confusing, but its hard to explain this class without sounding like its a class I'm teaching. Here is my code:

```
public class student
{
   private String name;
   private int year;
   private int age;
   private double gpa;
   /*
    * Default Constructor
    */
   public student()
   {
       name = "John";
       year = 2016;
       age = 16;
       gpa = 4.0;
   }
   /* 
    * other constructor
    */
   public student(String name, int year, int age, double gpa)
   {
       this.name = name;
       this.year = year;
       this.age = age;
       this.gpa = gpa;
   }
   /*
    * accessors
    */
   public String getName()
   {
       return name; 
   }
   public int getAge()
   {
       return age;
   }
   public int getYear()
   {
       return year;
   }
   public double getGpa()
   {
       return gpa;
   }
   /*
    * mutators
    */
   public void setName(String name)
   {
       this.name=name;
   }
   public void setGpa(double gpa)
   {
       this.gpa=gpa;
   }
   public void setYear(int year)
   {
       this.year=year;
   }
   public void setAge(int age)
   {
       this.age=age;
   }
   /*
    * calculate GPA
    */
   public double calcGpa(double points, int classes)
   {
      return double gpa; 
      gpa = points / classes; 
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to consider this a typo more than anything; the order in which you calculate the GPA and you return the GPA is backwards.  Also, you don't need the `double` keyword in front of `return` either.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks, that worked. Now, how would I retrieve my information using toString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calcGpa method can be something like this:

```
public double calcGpa(double points, int classes)
   {
      gpa = points / classes;
      return gpa;
   }
```

and for change the toString method you can override it. something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    return getName() + " : " + getGpa() 
}
```

Comment: That worked in term of compiling, but in my other file where in putting data, it is telling me that gpa has private access in student. Should I upload my other file to show you what I'm doing there?

Comment: I think you should read more about java. when you define a variable as private, you can not access it in other classes. you have written getter and setter methods, so for accessing the gpa from other classes, you can use `getGpa()` method. (I've updated the sample code)